# Zoom for reputation graph for SE account is broken

Tags: bug, stack-exchange, reputation-graph

[Reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/3917114/alexolut?tab=reputation) axises for SE account show wrong values after zooming.

Initially (looks fine):

> [image: init]

After zoom Y-axis has wrong values (e.g. 10k is lower than 6k):

> [image: zoom]

After reseting zoom I expect to see same graph as initially, but see overlapped values on X-axis and weird ordering for Y-axis (5 - 7.5 - 12 - **10** - 15):

> [image: reset]